# Does Matlab's fmincon() do automatic gradient scaling?

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm currently working with Matlab for a constrained nonlinear optimization problem where I supply analytic jacobians for both the objective and contraints. `fmincon()` is able to find a solution for this problem without scaling the constraint and objective functions (i.e. with `ScaleProblem` set to `false`) but I'm wondering if `fmincon()` is scaling the analytic jacobians automatically, as I'm having trouble replicating the result using other packages (e.g. IPOPT) without gradient scaling. If scaling is being performed, how exactly is this scaling being done?

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html?s_tid=srchtitle_fmincon_1#busog7r-options):

> ScaleProblem  `true` causes the algorithm to normalize all constraints and the objective function. Disable by setting to the default `false`.
>
> For `optimset`, the values are `'obj-and-constr'` or `'none'`. See [Current and Legacy Option Names](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/current-and-legacy-option-name-tables.html).

So it normalises the objective function and all constraints. If the function is non-obfuscated, you can use `edit fmincon` to open it and see whether that can shed more light on the matter. If it's obfuscated/built-in though, the only ones with more knowledge would be The MathWorks themselves.